# Get Yesterday's Date (MS Power Automate)

Tags: power-automate

In Microsoft Power Automate, using the expression `utcNow()` you can get the current date (and time). I am trying to get yesterday's date. I tried `dateadd(utcNow(), -1)` and similar code, but nothing works. Anyone know how to work with dates in Microsoft Power Automate?

Answer (score 8):

**addDays** is the function you're looking for:

```
//Yesterday
addDays(utcnow(),-1)

//Next Week
addDays(utcnow(),7)
```

Comment: Just keep in mind timezones. As you start moving away from UTC, you may get unexpected results.
To account for this you can do:
addDays(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd'),-1)
Replacing 'Eastern Standard Time' with your timezone. There is a full list at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912391(v=winembedded.11)

Answer (score 5):

This code seems to work for me:

```
formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1),'MM.dd.yyyy')
```

I have used the `dormatDateTime`: function to get the date to change to format to what I want it to be

`addDays`: can be used to travel to and fro in dates like if I want to go back one day it will be -1 if I want it to go ahead one day it would be +1 or 1.

`utcNow()`: Gets me the current date and time

Now I can get the date in formats like "MM/dd/yyyy" or "MM.dd.yyyy" or "MM dd yyyy". This list of delimiters can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/format-datetimefunction).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use one of the newer built-in `Date Time` actions. Use `Get past time` and set it to 1 day interval to get yesterday:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use addDays():

```
addDays(utcNow(),-1)
```

Moreover you have addMinutes(), addHours(), addSeconds().

Answer (score 1):

You can use getPastTime(interval,TimeUnit,format?) function.
It gives you the current time minus specified time interval. You can find this function in expression tab.

Here is the code for yesterday's date

```
getPastTime(1, 'Day', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Where,
second argument is Day, Month or Year, first argument is number and last argument is format of the date you want to achieve.

If today's date is "21/06/2023" then you will get "20-06-2023" as a result.